# Can't use ViewPager with androidx

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm trying to implement ViewPager in my layout, but after importing     `implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'` I can't get it from the xml

[image]

I can't find it anywhere after implementing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After **Restart and invalidate cache** it worked !